Coloring points on a graph proportionately
I have this graph in R:
library(igraph)

width <- 30
height <- 20
num_nodes <- width * height

x <- rep(1:width, each = height)
y <- rep(1:height, times = width)

g <- make_empty_graph(n = num_nodes, directed = FALSE)

get_node_index <- function(i, j) (i - 1) * height + j

edges <- c()
for(i in 1:width) {
    for(j in 1:height) {
        current_node <- get_node_index(i, j)
        
        if(i < width) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i + 1, j))
        
        if(j < height) edges <- c(edges, current_node, get_node_index(i, j + 1))
    }
}

g <- add_edges(g, edges)

V(g)$x <- x
V(g)$y <- y

par(mfrow=c(1,1))

V(g)$name <- 1:num_nodes
plot(g, vertex.size = 7, vertex.label = V(g)$name, vertex.label.cex = 0.6, main = "Map with         Node Indices")


I want to pick some node on this graph, and color all nodes on this graph proportional to how far they are located from this node. That is, all nodes of the same distance have the same color - and nodes closer to the node are darker colored vs nodes that are farther away are lighter colored.
Based on my previous question (Calculating the shortest distance between multiple points on a graph?), I tried to do this (e.g. select node 50):
distances_from_50 <- distances(g, v = 50, to = V(g))
max_dist <- max(distances_from_50)

color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#08306B", "#F7FBFF"))(max_dist + 1)

V(g)$color <- color_palette[distances_from_50 + 1]

V(g)$color[50] <- "red"

par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(5,4,4,2))
plot(g, 
     vertex.size = 7,
     vertex.label = V(g)$value,
     vertex.label.cex = 0.6,
     main = "Distance-based Color Gradient from Node 50",
     layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y))


Is there something else that can be done so that nodes with darker colors still have visible labels?

I think this depends on your subjective perception about color differentiation. You can define a color palette specifically for vertex labels, e.g.,
labelcolor_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "lightyellow", "red", "purple", "black"))(max_dist + 1)
V(g)$labelcolor <- labelcolor_palette[distances_from_50 + 1]
plot(g,
    vertex.size = 7,
    vertex.label = V(g)$value,
    vertex.label.cex = 1,
    vertex.label.color = V(g)$labelcolor,
    main = "Distance-based Color Gradient from Node 50",
    layout = cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y)
)



thank you for your answer! apart from the color of the numbers, do you think my coding ideas are correct here? i.e. how to color nodes closer as darker and nodes further as lighter?

@farrow90 I think you are doing right

thank you for your feedback. if you have time later, can you please check out this question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79185801/simulating-random-numbers-between-ranges-that-sum-to-a-constant
