Simulating random numbers between ranges that sum to a constant?
This is a follow-up question to a question I posted earlier.
A while back, I posted this question on how to randomly split a graph into connected subgraphs : Randomly Split a Graph into Mini Graphs:
library(igraph)
n_rows <- 10
n_cols <- 5
g <- make_lattice(dimvector = c(n_cols, n_rows))

layout <- layout_on_grid(g, width = n_cols)

n_nodes <- vcount(g)
node_colors <- rep("white", n_nodes)

for (row in 0:(n_rows-1)) {
    start_index <- row * n_cols + 1
    node_colors[start_index:(start_index+2)] <- "orange"  
    node_colors[(start_index+3):(start_index+4)] <- "purple"    
}

node_labels <- 1:n_nodes

plot(g, 
     layout = layout, 
     vertex.color = node_colors,
     vertex.label = node_labels,
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.size = 15,
     edge.color = "gray",
     main = "Rectangular Undirected Network")


I used one of the (amazing) answers provided to run this function multiple times (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78982967/26653497):
library(igraph)
library(data.table)

f <- function(g, n) {
    m <- length(g)
    dt <- setDT(as_data_frame(g))
    dt <- rbindlist(list(dt, dt[,.(from = to, to = from)]))
    dt[,group := 0L]
    used <- logical(m)
    s <- sample(m, n)
    used[s] <- TRUE
    m <- m - n
    dt[from %in% s, group := .GRP, from]
    
    while (m) {
        dt2 <- unique(
            dt[group != 0L & !used[to], .(grow = to, onto = group)][sample(.N)],
            by = "grow"
        )
        dt[dt2, on = .(from = grow), group := onto]
        used[dt2[[1]]] <- TRUE
        m <- m - nrow(dt2)
    }
    
    unique(dt[,to := NULL])[,.(vertices = .(from)), group]
}


plot_multiple_subgraphs <- function(n_plots = 25, n_rows = 10, n_cols = 5, n_subgraphs = 5) {
    g <- make_lattice(dimvector = c(n_cols, n_rows))
    layout <- layout_on_grid(g, width = n_cols)
    n_nodes <- vcount(g)
    
    color_palette <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple")
    
    par(mfrow = c(5, 5), mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 2, 0.5))
    
    for (i in 1:n_plots) {
        subgraphs <- f(g, n_subgraphs)
        
        node_colors <- rep("white", n_nodes)
        
        for (j in 1:nrow(subgraphs)) {
            nodes <- unlist(subgraphs$vertices[j])
            node_colors[nodes] <- color_palette[j]
        }
        
        plot(g, 
             layout = layout, 
             vertex.color = node_colors,
             vertex.label = NA,  
             vertex.size = 15,   
             edge.color = "gray",
             edge.width = 0.5,  
             main = paste("Partition", i),  
             cex.main = 0.8)     
    }
}

plot_multiple_subgraphs()


I am now wondering - is there a way to add constraints to this function? For example, I want 7 random connected subgraphs such that each graph has minimum 5% of all nodes and maximum 25% of all nodes?
I wrote this small function which generates 7 random numbers that sum to 100 such that the smallest number is larger than 5 and the largest number is smaller than 25:
generate_one_set <- function(n = 7, total = 100, min_val = 5, max_val = 25) {
  repeat {
    points <- sort(c(0, runif(n-1), 1))
    numbers <- diff(points) * total
    if(min(numbers) >= min_val && max(numbers) <= max_val) {
      return(round(numbers, 2))
    }
  }
}

set.seed(123) 
for(i in 1:5) {
    result <- generate_one_set()
    print(result)
    cat("Sum:", sum(result), "\n\n")
}

[1] 12.75  7.90 16.79 18.65 19.24 14.17 10.50
Sum: 100 

[1]  9.48 17.95 10.96  6.45 21.66 14.95 18.54
Sum: 99.99 

[1] 18.38  8.19 14.71 21.72 11.66 11.71 13.64
Sum: 100.01 

[1] 16.81  9.95 13.69 12.67  6.20 19.22 21.47
Sum: 100.01 

[1]  8.63 11.57  8.10 13.74 16.68 21.94 19.33
Sum: 99.99 

Can I somehow introduce this constraint into the earlier function?

I've seen generalized brute force approaches where you generate outputs in a while loop, discarding any that don't work. But a more optimized approach will generally require domain knowledge to make sure the results are appropriate, e.g. suitably randomized and not biased.

@Jon Spring: Thank you for your feedback...

If you are referring to the size of each group (which should consist of 0.05 ~ 0.25 of all nodes), probably you can try rmultinom, e.g.,
K <- 7
N <- n_rows * n_cols
minRho <- 0.05
maxRho <- 0.25
minSz <- ceiling(minRho * N)
repeat {
    p <- rmultinom(1, N - minSz * K, rep(1, K)) + minSz
    if (all(p <= maxRho * N)) break
}

and you will obtain something like
> p
     [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]    9
[3,]    6
[4,]    6
[5,]    7
[6,]    7
[7,]    9

> sum(p)
[1] 50


It seems your problem is similar to your previous question, so you can replace the code for partitioning (see the corresponding lines in the answer) with the code above, then it should work with size constraints.

thank you so much! I really like the answer you provided in the current question! Do you think its ok just to use this?

@farrow90 i think so

I combined both your answers into a single answer. Would you like to see it? thank you so much for all your help

@farrow90 yes, please show how you merge them if you want

sure, will post soon! :)

Hi ThomasIsCoding, my apologies for not getting back to you sooner. I have been feeling ill these last few days. I completely forgot to post this. I am still cleaning up the code. I recently posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79242825/making-sure-that-colors-are-properly-placed-in-graphs .  Can you please take a look at it if you have time? Wishing you and your family all the best for the upcoming holiday season. Thanks
